# Is there a fix for Win32::Unicode::File installation in Win 10, 1903 with Strawberry perl 5.30.2.1

Tags: file, perl, unicode

Installation of `Win32::Unicode::File` module in Windows 10 1903 (North America ACP 1252) fails with `cpan Win32::Unicode::File`.

Strawberry perl installation `uname='Win32 strawberry-perl 5.30.2.1 #1 Tue Mar 17 03:21:32 2020 x64'`

```
C:\temp\work>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 30, subversion 2 (v5.30.2) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2020, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

The problem was documented in Perl Monks [post](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1208723) from 2018.

Is there a fix for the problem?

```
C:\temp\work>cpan Win32::Unicode::File
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.217)
Database was generated on Thu, 11 Jun 2020 18:42:49 GMT
Running install for module 'Win32::Unicode::File'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.093)
Checksum for C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\X\XA\XAICRON\Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.36)
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.81)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20200314)
Configuring X/XA/XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Writing ppport.h
.......
.......
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_print.t           (Wstat: 768 Tests: 13 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Non-zero exit status: 3
Files=27, Tests=284, 28 wallclock secs ( 0.30 usr +  0.06 sys =  0.36 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/27 test programs. 3/284 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:1038: test_dynamic] Error 255
  XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
  C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::Unicode::File'.
```

Update:

I was referred by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) to following [information](https://github.com/xaicron/p5-win32-unicode/issues/7) that failed test can be ignored with forceful installation.

An attempt of forced installation with `cpan -f -i Win32::Unicode::File` fails with following message

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04_print.t           (Wstat: 768 Tests: 13 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  1-3
  Non-zero exit status: 3
Files=27, Tests=284, 28 wallclock secs ( 0.25 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.30 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/27 test programs. 3/284 subtests failed.
gmake: *** [Makefile:1038: test_dynamic] Error 255
  XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
  C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
Running make install for XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
"C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-Iinc" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Unicode.bs blib\arch\auto\Win32\Unicode\Unicode.bs 644
Files found in blib\arch: installing files in blib\lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\perl\site\lib\auto\Win32\Unicode\Unicode.xs.dll
Appending installation info to C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
  XAICRON/Win32-Unicode-0.38.tar.gz
  C:\bin\Portable\strawberry-perl\c\bin\gmake.exe install UNINST=1 -- OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::Unicode::File'.
```

Comment: Re "*An attempt of forced installation [...] fails*", Actually, it was successful (`gmake.exe install -- OK`). The installation would have failed but for `-f`, so I guess that last line is weird (bad) way of saying that?

Comment: Agreed, the last message is somewhat confusing. In other post I wrote a small script confirms that it does work and produces desired/expected outcome. Hmm, the issue with the test was known for a long time, but it seems that the code was _touched_ last time in 2012 (abandoned by maintainer?) [testers matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Win32-Unicode+0.38)

Comment: Re "*the last message is somewhat confusing.*", yeah, that's an understatement :) /// I'm planning on identifying the problem later today with W::U's test today.

Comment: Merely trying to force install something that is broken is not generally helpful. In these cases, your next step is to run the failing test as you would a normal perl program to see what's going on. The test could be bad or the module could be broken. `perl -Iblib/lib t/04_print.t`. Look at the code for the failing tests to suss out where things go wrong. Then, file an issue with the module with what you have found.

Comment: @briandfoy -- It looks like maintainer of the module abandoned it. Are you suggest that I take over the maintenance of this module?

Comment: I’m not suggesting anything other than what I said. Even if the issue is not fixed, it’s report is helpful to other people.

Comment: @briandfoy -- As far as I can see the issue was initially reported on Aug 8, 2012 -- [testers matrix](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Win32-Unicode+0.38)

Comment: I retract what I said previously. [`printW`'s design is broken](https://github.com/xaicron/p5-win32-unicode/issues/7#issuecomment-644699287). Fixing this issue requires fundamentally changing `printW`